# How to check if JSON file is not empty and load JSON data from file in temp folder correctly?

Tags: python, temporary-files

The problem is that the process never goes through "loaded" JSON data from a file, and I do not understand why. It always goes through creating the new file each time.

```
import argparse
import os
import tempfile
import json

storage = argparse.ArgumentParser()
storage.add_argument("--key", help="input key's name")
storage.add_argument("--val", help="value of key", default=None)
args = storage.parse_args()
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')

with open(storage_path,'r') as f:
    if f.seek(2) is not 2:
        data_base = json.load(f)
        print('loaded that: ',data_base)
    else:
        f.close()
        print('each time I am creating the new one')
        with open(storage_path,'w') as f:
            data_base = {}
        f.close()

if data_base.get(args.key, 'Not found') == 'Not found': 
    if args.val is not None:
        data_base.setdefault(args.key, args.val)
        with open(storage_path, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data_base, f)
            print('dumped this: ',data_base)
```

Comment: If you're using Python 2.7.x, `file.seek()` returns `None`.   Also don't use identity testing (`is`) for equality test - it is not garanteed in anyway that `2 is 2` (it will actually  'work' in CPython but that's an accident due to an implementation detail)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I am using python 3.6.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code, ie

program crashing if the file does not exist:

```
with open(storage_path,'r') as f:
```

opening `storage_path` for writing but actually not writing anything:

```
    print('each time I am creating the new one')
    with open(storage_path,'w') as f:
        data_base = {}
    f.close()
```

And actually if you happened to have `f.seek(2) == 2`, the `json.load(f)` would also crash since at this point you moved the file pointer at the 3rd char so subsequent read in `json.load()` wouldn't get the whole content.

Here's a fixed version that should work AFAICT:

```
import argparse
import os
import tempfile
import json

storage = argparse.ArgumentParser()
storage.add_argument("--key", help="input key's name")
storage.add_argument("--val", help="value of key", default=None)
args = storage.parse_args()
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')

data_base = None
if os.path.exists(storage_path):
    with open(storage_path,'r') as f:
        try:
            data_base = json.load(f)
            print('loaded that: ',data_base)
        except Exception as e:
            print("got %s on json.load()" % e)

if data_base is None:
    print('each time I am creating the new one')
    data_base = {}
    with open(storage_path,'w') as f:
        json.dump(data_base, f)

# don't prevent the user to set `"Not found" as value, if might
# be a legitimate value.
# NB : you don't check if `args.key` is actually set... maybe you should ?

sentinel = object()    
if data_base.get(args.key, sentinel) is sentinel:         
    if args.val is not None:
        data_base[args.key] = args.val
        with open(storage_path, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data_base, f)
            print('dumped this: ',data_base)
```

Comment: >>you don't check if `args.key` is actually set... maybe you should ?
Actually argparse does it for me, does not it?

Comment: @pure_true Nope, it doesn't.  Options are, well, optional, you know ? Unless you explicitely make them not optional that is : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required